# How to change the SendIcon in WebChat

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to replace the send icon on the WebChat. I'm able to change the colors of the existing icon but how could I replace the SVG image by another one?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't looking to fork and build the repo, an alternative is to change the element directly in the html. Generally speaking, changing the DOM directly in a React environment is not best practice, however, in this case, the results appear to be stable.

There is also an open issue on the BotFramework-WebChat repo ([#1839](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1839)) that is discussing making the sendBox customizable. No ETA on when that might happen, but something to keep in mind.

To include this on your page, add the code starting at `const parent`. Be sure to set your image size to 28x28 if you want to maintain the same size as the current arrow.

```html
<script>
  ( async function () {
    const res = await fetch( 'http://somesite/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
    const { token } = await res.json();

    [...]

    document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();

    const parent = document.getElementsByClassName( 'main' )
    const child = parent[0].children[2].getElementsByTagName('svg');
    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src= 'bot - small.png';
    svg.setAttribute('height', '28');
    svg.setAttribute('width', '28');
    svg.appendChild(img);
    child[0].replaceWith(img);

    }
  )().catch( err => console.error( err ) );
</script>
```

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: I used DOM code in the componentDidMount and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the icon cannot be changed as a setting currently.

But you can still fork the repository and change the icon, its definition is located here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/SendBox/Assets/SendIcon.js

```
import React from 'react';

const SendIcon = () => (
  <svg height={28} viewBox="0 0 45.7 33.8" width={28}>
    <path clipRule="evenodd" d="M8.55 25.25l21.67-7.25H11zm2.41-9.47h19.26l-21.67-7.23zm-6 13l4-11.9L5 5l35.7 11.9z" />
  </svg>
);

export default SendIcon;
```